# What language are the soldiers speaking in Mission 19 "On the Trail"?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

In Metal Gear Solid 5 what language do the soldiers speak in mission 19? I can't interrogate anyone.

By mistake I discarded my Kikongo interpreter. But I have my Russian, Afrikaans and Pashto interpreters on the Support Team.

Also when I check my Support Team detail it says I can translate Kikongo with `S rank`

If they are speaking Kikongo, is there a way I can find another interpreter? I went on free roam to post #16 in Africa to see if I can find him again with no luck.

**NOTE:** I can't replay SIDE OP #4, it's greyed out.

Comment: @Frank  That tag isnt consistent with other metal gear tags. because I saw `metal-gear-solid-1` ... `metal-gear-solid-2` up to `metal-gear-solid-4` That is why I didnt find it on first place :(.

Comment: Yeah, it's unfortunately too long if we keep the same convention.  So it had to be shortened.

Comment: @Frank I came from stack overflow, and there I can create related tags. So maybe you can create `metal-gear-solid-5` and make it related to `mgs-5-the-phantom-pain`?? to keep it consistent?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza - I have added a new `metal-gear-solid-5` tag and suggested it as a synonym [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags/mgs-5-the-phantom-pain/synonyms) for people to vote on. I believe it makes sense for consistency reasons as you mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

If you replay [**Side Op #4 - Extract Interpreter**](http://uk.ign.com/wikis/metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain/4._Extract_Interpreter_(Kikongo)), this is the mission in which you get your first Kikongo interpreter.

I'm not 100% sure of what language they are speaking, but if this is the only one you are missing and cannot interpret them, I'd go and re extract the interpreter from this mission.

Comment: I cant reply Side Op #4 :(

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Do you have any other missions to do? Some side ops become replayable after a certain amount of time.

Comment: Only #50 Im scare to face that big robot again :P,  Already at 88% need S rank some missions and complete some goals. And dont know why the rest of Side OP arent available yet, still are like 10 not unlocked yet. And the usually ~20 SideOP I already complete on white but not #4 on those.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to understand a language as long as you had the interpreter in the Support Team at some point, you won't lose the ability to interrogate soldiers after dismissing an interpreter. Perhaps this functionality was added after your question.